# How to manage systemoutofmemory exception?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-management, out-of-memory, stack-overflow

I am dealing with approximately 3 gb of data. It is stored in an Oracle database. My task is listing this data on datagridview. That's why I created a class to store this data and then I am using this genericList to push datagridview's datasource. Nevertheless after approximately 1300 rows of data were handled in ram, the code returns a "stackoutofmemory" exception. And the program stops running.

I tried to clear genericList data after 1300 mb of data was uploaded and I used garbage collection to clear data in ram. But it didn't work. vshost32.exe was still increased.

```
var dataList = cmd=........... // get dataList from DB
list<class> dataList2 = new list<class>();

foreach(var data in dataList) {
     dataList2.add(new class{
    ...........//fill the DataList2
});

datagridview.datasource = datalist2;
```

I expected my genericlist will run properly after genericList was filled . But vshost32.exe was thrown systemoutofmemory exception.

Comment: why would you need to load 3 GB of data in your ram/in a List?
What are your trying to achive in the end maybe we can look for a better solution. 
Keep in mind that clearing the list @ XXXmb might fix the issue for you but might cause the same issue on lower spec devices with less ram

Comment: Actually i dont have any limit about hardware .I am using 16gb Ram with 500gb SSD . I thought my hardware run this easily. But somehow visual studio throws systemoutofexception . i dont get it .

Comment: but still why do you want to do this in first place?
and what is actaually stored in saied list?

Comment: because i need 3 gb on datagridview.I will add some filter attribute top of the datagridview. and i will process the data on datagridview for instance update,delete or insert. But i want to see all data in datagridview. Otherwise i can't process the data.

Comment: `DataGridView` was never designed to handle such a ludicrously huge amount of data. I seriously doubt that you actually need all 3GB of data in-memory at once.

Comment: Probably you should consider the implementation of some type of paging.

Comment: Retrieve only data that is filtered. If no filter is present, just show latest 100 and add paging.

Comment: if you want help i can only reapeat:
What kind of data do you have stored in the list?
for example if it containse images consider only loading references to the data instead of the actual data and load the images as needed (just as an example)
Your GUI should never be asked to handle this amount of data. Or if you have to, create a copy on the harddrive and handle the information there
Your ram is not ment for Datastorage but for data prosessing

Comment: i just store name,surname,email.adress,quantity,...... string or decimal type

Answer (score 1):

There are couple issues that you are dealing with, let's discuss them one by one:

> I am dealing with approximately 3 GB of data. It is stored in an Oracle database. My task is listing this data on datagridview

Firstly no-one can review 3 GB data in one go that's why its always seen in parts, that's why data is paginated to give a limited page view

> That's why I created a class to store this data and then I am using this genericList to push datagridview's datasource

Most of the data structures like datagridview's datasource, have an internal limit, they are not meant to store this huge data, it will either break the data structure or make the performance very poor

> I tried to clear genericList data after 1300 mb of data was uploaded and I used garbage collection to clear data in ram. But it didn't work. vshost32.exe was still increased.

There are couple of points here, not sure how did you clear the data @ 1300 MB, but you are surely using 32 bit process, which has the user limit of 2 GB and hence OOM on crossing that limit. Remaining 2 GB is for kernel process, which you may adjust to maximum 3 GB for the user process, but generally you are dealing with Data structure's internal limit or it is purely your assumption that you clear any memory, since GC is especially not deterministic, it goes over the boundary rather quickly

> What is the solution ?

1. Use 64 bit process on a 64 bit system, which will make sure that Out of memory exception goes away, since the memory limit now is 2^64 bytes = 16 ExaBytes. You can ensure that process / binary is 64 bit compatible
2. Store the data in a in memory cache and bind only a page or two to the Data grid source, Cache is better suited for this kind of data, its quick access especially if you are not out of RAM

Mostly in a 64 bit process its never Out of memory, since no system generally have higher RAM than 16 ExaBytes, even if only half is assigned for the user process

Comment: Does the gc even touch the data? There is a referece to it so it wont collect it i think. Correct me if i m wrong. Plus as far as i am aware calling the garbage collector manually is bad practice isnt it?

Comment: @DenisSchaf assuming the data is still referenced, GC cannot touch it, but let's assume OP release it, still GC is not deterministic, even if use GC APIs explicitly and here probably GC has no time to pitch in by the time memory is on verge of OOM, there's no way GC can optimize and system throw an exception.
Ideally GC apis are meant for test systems, to explicit wait for pending finalizers or generation collection but not meant for the production code. At best we can use Workstation or Server GC, which is a configuration